# Google GCM token - token refresh

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

It's been asked already but all the answers I found were expired I think. I'm not sure I understand the whole procedure correctly.

When does the token change? Can it change all of a sudden and the phone is notified with a new one? Do I have to implement such possibility in my application? Or once registered it will stay the same until app is reinstalled?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the GCM and I have checked the tokens on different devices, Google provides the same token with the same device. if I remember correctly it depends on the API_KEY used in your application. If you change the API_KEY, change the token of the device.